# Random Sounds on Galaxy S8

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have  Samsung Galaxy S8, recently the device started making sounds randomly from time to time (it sound like crow or monkey), i don't see any notification and I can't find the app source for it.

it is not the NFC or the notification reminder both are turned off.

is there a log that tell us which app played sound?
any other ideas?

Comment: Did you recently install an app? Maybe it's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was a weather application with a widget.
it didn't display any notification

so I enabled USB debugging on my device, connected it to the computer and started monitor the log (logcat) using SDK Device Monitor (I used what I have from Visual Studio 2017)
I discover that once i here the sound, there is some app that use the MediaPlayer
I got it PID and using running `ps` on `adb shell` 
I was able to detect the app.